# Connection Upgrade on React-Native

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, react-native, websocket

So i'm currently develloping an app using React-Native and i have to implement Websocket.
Now i'm trying to connect my app to Mattermost. For ws, we have to begin with an html get request, that will be upgraded to a ws request.
Example :

```
URL: https://URL/api/v3/users/websocket
Méthod : GET
Adress : 10.10.10.10:8080
Code d’état : 200

Response (39 o) 
Server  "nginx"
Date    "Tue, 08 Aug 2017 12:33:21 GMT"
Connection  "upgrade"
Upgrade "websocket"
Sec-WebSocket-Accept    "vG2CYVx3/p+6ei/8e5fGMN8qq7A="

Request's header (769 o)    
Host    "URL"
User-Agent  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; … Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
Accept  "text/html,application/xhtml+x…lication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate, br"
Sec-WebSocket-Version   "13"
Origin  "URL"
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions    "permessage-deflate"
Sec-WebSocket-Key   "HsX9INf0fr7x0cQAglMyjg=="
Cookie  "MMAUTHTOKEN=7xaaaaaaaaahezhatnwxwih;"
Connection  "keep-alive, Upgrade"
Upgrade "websocket"
```

So my question is how to do an upgradable connexion on react, and use it to make a wss connection.

For the moment i was using axios to make my html requests and socket.io for my websocket connection.

Comment: Why upgrade and not create a new normal ws connection? I'm sorry but I really don't understand the question. Maybe you can expand on the part you say: "but now I have to connect it to the real website"

Comment: can you this question little bit more

Comment: @Borjante I don't have the choise, i have to connect my app to a Mattermost server, and sadly matermost upgrade the connection

Comment: @ashutoshpandey i'll edit

Comment: Good edit, sadly I can't help you on this one

Comment: @Borjante not a problem , thank you anyway to have took a look on my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution.
Just downloaded [this](https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-driver-javascript/blob/master/websocket_client.jsx) driver and include it in my App:

```
import Websocket from "../Applications/websocket_client"

export default class SecWatt extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        webs = new Websocket();
        webs.setEventCallback(printEvent);
        webs.initialize("wss://*MattermostURL*/api/v3/users/websocket" , "YourToken");
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <View>
            </View>
        );
    }    
}

function printEvent(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }
```